# Reading Excel File! Always appear an dialog ask for save

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to read data from excel file. My problem is when I finished reading it's always appear an dialog ask for save. How can I turn off it?
[image]
Here is my code:

```
Missing missing = Missing.Value;
            Excel.Application _app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook _workBook = _app.Workbooks.Open(e.Argument.ToString());
            Excel.Worksheet _workSheet = _workBook.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range _range = _workSheet.UsedRange;
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            for (int i = 0; i < _range.Rows.Count; i++) {
                if (_workSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value != null && _workSheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value != null)
                {
                    inputList.Add(new infoInput(_workSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value, _workSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value));
                }
                bw.ReportProgress(((i + 1) * 100)/_workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count);
            }
            _workBook.Close();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_workBook);
             _app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            _app.Quit();
```

P/S Sorry for my English! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `DisplayAlerts` property to FALSE to prevent this message when you call `.Quit()` method.

```
_app.DisplayAlerts = false;
_app.Quit();
//or
Application excelApp = new Application();
Workbooks excelWorkbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
var item = excelWorkbooks.Open(....
item.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
excelWorkbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
item.Close();
excelWorkbooks.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

[_Application.Quit method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.ASPX):

> If unsaved workbooks are open when you use this method, Microsoft
> Excel displays a dialog box asking whether you want to save the
> changes. You can prevent this by saving all workbooks before using the
> Quit method or by setting the DisplayAlerts property to False. When
> this property is False, Microsoft Excel doesn’t display the dialog box
> when you quit with unsaved workbooks; it quits without saving them.

Comment: Thanks for rely? Let me ask you a question? Is excel application still running in task manager?

Comment: Sorry! But it still show the dialog say: "Want to save your change..."

Comment: @hicurin Try to insert `_app.DisplayAlerts = false;` before `_workBook.Close();` I guess this method display this dialog. Also you can call [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close.aspx) with a parameter `_workBook.Close(false);`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this

```
_workBook.Close(SaveChanges:false)
```

or

```
WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

according to this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

if you omit this parameter, a save dialog will appear.

> If there are no changes to the workbook, this argument is ignored. If
>   there are changes to the workbook and the workbook appears in other
>   open windows, this argument is ignored. If there are changes to the
>   workbook but the workbook does not appear in any other open windows,
>   this argument specifies whether changes should be saved, as shown in
>   the following list.
>
> true. Saves the changes to the workbook. If there is not yet a file
>   name associated with the workbook, then FileName is used. If FileName
>   is omitted, the user is asked to supply a file name.
>
> false. Does not save the changes to the workbook.
>
> Omitted. Displays a dialog box asking the user whether or not to save
>   changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  All the suggestions about macros, repairing MS Office, etc. were no help at all -- although they were related to the problem ...

It turns out that I accidentally changed a date in one cell of the spreadsheet from a valid date -- ex: 02/06/2021 -- to the letter "H".  I don't know when I did it, but it was not a temporary change -- i.e., I apparently hit Enter or an arrow kay after the change.  Interestingly, that cell was NOT linked to any macros or formulas; it just was formatted as a date.  When I repaired the date, and saved the spreadsheet, the problem went away for good.